# MarkupBuilder's setEscapeAttributes not working?

Tags: groovy

I expect the `setEscapeAttributes( Boolean )` method to switch on and off of escaping special characters, namely, when I convert the builder content into string, special characters will be different, depending on what value we feed into that method. However, it seems either my expectation is not right or the method is not working properly. Here is an example snippet:

**foo.groovy**

```
import groovy.xml.*
def writer = new StringWriter()
def builder = new MarkupBuilder( writer )
println builder.isEscapeAttributes()
builder.setEscapeAttributes( false )
println builder.isEscapeAttributes()
builder.html {
    h2 "hello<br>world"
}

println writer.toString()
```

If you run `groovy foo.groovy`, here is the output:

```
true
false
<html>
  <h2>hello&lt;br&gt;world</h2>
</html>
```

where I expect the `h2` line to be

```
<h2>hello<br>world</h2>
```

So, what is going on? I am using groovy 2.1.8, the latest one as of this writing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

using `setEscapeAttributes` will stop it escaping `attributes`, so:

```
println new StringWriter().with { writer ->
    new MarkupBuilder( writer ).with {

        // Tell the builder to not escape ATTRIBUTES
        escapeAttributes = false

        html {
            h2( tim:'woo>yay' )
        }
        writer.toString()
    }
}
```

Will print:

```
<html>
  <h2 tim='woo>yay' />
</html>
```

as opposed to this if you comment out the `escapeAttributes` line above:

```
<html>
  <h2 tim='woo&gt;yay' />
</html>
```

If you want to avoid escaping content, you need to use `mkp.yieldUnescaped` like so:

```
println new StringWriter().with { writer ->
    new MarkupBuilder( writer ).with {
        html {
            h2 {
                mkp.yieldUnescaped 'hello<br>world'
            }
        }
        writer.toString()
    }
}
```

Which will print:

```
<html>
  <h2>hello<br>world</h2>
</html>
```

Though care should be taken, as this is obviously invalid xml (as the `
 is not closed)