# MarkupBuilder don't escape element value

Tags: groovy

I am trying to generate HTML using MarkupBuilder and would like to know if I can turn of escaping values, see example below.

```
    new MarkupBuilder().with {
        setEscapeAttributes(false)
        p('Hello <strong>World!</strong>')
        p('Hello ') { strong('World!') }
    }
```

The strong tag within the first p tag is escaped. The second strong tag within the second p tag is not escaped. How can I configure MarkupBuilder to not escape the strong tag in the first p tag?

```
<p>Hello &lt;strong&gt;World!&lt;/strong&gt;</p>
<p>Hello 
  <strong>World!</strong>
</p>
```

Comment: Have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19486750/markupbuilders-setescapeattributes-not-working

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MarkupBuilder's setEscapeAttributes not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19486750/markupbuilders-setescapeattributes-not-working)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`escapeAttributes` works for attributes.  You're not setting attributes

You need to use `mkp.yieldUnescaped`

```
new MarkupBuilder().with {
    p { mkp.yieldUnescaped 'Hello <strong>World!</strong>' }
    p('Hello ') { strong('World!') }
}
```